# Why does boto3 not consistently find my table in local DynamoDB?

Tags: python, flask, amazon-dynamodb

I'm running a local dockerised DynamoDB:

```
~ docker run -d -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local
```

...which has a table in it, created via the aws dynamodb CLI*.

From an ipython shell boto3 can find the table without a problem:

```
db = boto3.resource('dynamodb',
                    endpoint_url='http://localhost:8000',
                    region_name='eu-west-2')

print([t for t in db.tables.all()])

# ==> [dynamodb.Table(name=u'myTable')]
```

...but when accessing this table from a breakpoint in a locally running flask application, boto3 can't find the table:

```
db = boto3.resource('dynamodb',
                    endpoint_url='http://localhost:8000',
                    region_name='eu-west-2')
[t for t in db.tables.all()]

# ==> []
```

I can't think of anything about the context of the flask application that would change how boto3 is working, so I'm kind of stuck. Why doesn't the call to `db.tables.all()` return the same in both cases?

Both contexts are running from the same virtualenv, using boto v1.7.1 and python 2.7.13

---

*CLI command used to create the table:

```
~ aws dynamodb create-table --table-name myTable --attribute-definitions AttributeName=api_key,AttributeType=S AttributeName=session_id,AttributeType=S AttributeName=time_stamp,AttributeType=N --key-schema AttributeName=session_id,KeyType=HASH --global-secondary-indexes IndexName=api_key-time_stamp-index,KeySchema=["{KeyType=HASH,AttributeName=api_key}","{KeyType=RANGE,AttributeName=time_stamp}"],Projection="{ProjectionType=ALL}",ProvisionedThroughput="{ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5}" --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 --region eu-west-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The problem was that I had my `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` in my environment variables at the time of running the flask application. I was aware that [boto3 automatically checks for the presence of these](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#configuring-credentials) when it is used, but I didn't realise this would have any effect on a **local** DynamoDB. Without diving into the source code, it looks like it is effectively partitioning the local DynamoDB into different instances for each `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, including the case where `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` is not set.

Comment: There is a parameter `-sharedDB` you can set when starting local dynamodb to just use one database and disregard the credentials.

Comment: @cementblocks nice! And in fact the 2nd bullet point [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.UsageNotes.html) explains the problem I had.